# Ideas for simplified linkedlist Implementation in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, linked-list

I want to implement something like a linkedlist in Kotlin. What I want is the ability to append more elements at the beginning or end of the list later on. I read that in java, there is unshift and push for doing this? But I couldnt find the equivalent ones in Kotlin.

I dont need the ability to delete elements from the list. If at all I have to delete, I would delete the whole list.

Kotlin experts, please let me know what is a good option for this.

Thanks.

Comment: Kotlin does have a `LinkedList ` in the standard library. Doesn't it fit your needs?

Comment: i thought it was much slower? I will need to access an element from the middle or end of the list. from what i know, using linkedlist I have to go to all previous elements for arriving at the desired element.

Comment: There is [ArrayDeque](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-array-deque/) in Kotlin but it's [experimental](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-experimental-stdlib-api/)

Comment: does this question have anything to do with android ? not being rude, just stating that you could be just looking for a pure kotlin answer

Comment: @a_local_nobody, ok i removed the android tag.

Comment: I don't think there are any data structures which give O(1) append/remove at both ends of the list _and_ O(1) indexed access in general.  So you'll probably need to judge how to balance those two requirements.  There are structures such as heaps and skip lists which can be _relatively_ fast at both, but it's always going to be a trade-off of some kind.  Or if the overall size was bounded, a circular buffer would give O(1) for both — at the cost of O(n) if it exceeded the buffer size.  Or… well, computer science has come up with a huge range of data structures!